# Send command via serial port in C#

Tags: c#, string, character-encoding, char, serial-port

I have to handle a chain of four motors using a serial port.
The user manual indicates that during initialization I need to send (for example) the strings

```
Z
1ECHO
2ECHO
3ECHO
4ECHO
```

And tells me to do that, in a code I do not recognize, with commands

```
PRINT(#128, "Z", #13)
PRINT(#129, "ECHO", #13)
PRINT(#130, "ECHO", #13)
PRINT(#131, "ECHO", #13)
PRINT(#132, "ECHO", #13)
```

To explain this, the manual also adds a sentence I do not understand:

> with the strings above you can initialize the motors via the motors
>   software but a host program have to send the same commands with different
>   prefix: 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 are in fact 0x80, 0x81, 0x82, 0x83 and 0x84,
>   respectively. The decimal equivalents of hexadecimal values ​​are 128,
>   129, 130, 131 and 132.

A colleague wrote a working code in Visual Basic as follows:

```
SerialPort.Output(chr(128) & "Z" & chr(13))
SerialPort.Output(chr(129) & "ECHO" & chr(13))
SerialPort.Output(chr(130) & "ECHO" & chr(13))
SerialPort.Output(chr(131) & "ECHO" & chr(13))
SerialPort.Output(chr(132) & "ECHO" & chr(13))
```

I've translated into .NET with:

```
SerialPort.Write((char)128 + "Z" + (char)13);
SerialPort.Write((char)129 + "ECHO" + (char)13);
SerialPort.Write((char)130 + "ECHO" + (char)13);
SerialPort.Write((char)131 + "ECHO" + (char)13);
SerialPort.Write((char)132 + "ECHO" + (char)13);
```

But it does not work.

Now I can not try but I wonder if it can work to rewrite my code like this:

```
SerialPort.Write("Z" + (char)13);
SerialPort.Write("1ECHO" + (char)13);
SerialPort.Write("2ECHO" + (char)13);
SerialPort.Write("3ECHO" + (char)13);
SerialPort.Write("4ECHO" + (char)13);
```

If it will work, why does it work?
And if it does not work, how do I correctly translate my colleague's code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use [SerialPort.Write(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2sxhat8(v=vs.110).aspx) with default encoding for sending bytes >128 (0x80), for more info see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2sxhat8(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2). If you need to be sure your data match any binary protocol, you should send data as array of `byte`s:

```
var data = new byte[] { 129, (byte)'E', (byte)'C', (byte)'H', (byte)'O', 13 };
SerialPort.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Then you will be sure no unwanted conversion is performed before sending.